# Linux setuid bit

Tags: linux, bash, setuid

As a normal user I can't seem to run the following bash script:

```
#/bin/bash
date 121001102020
```

The file permissions are:  4755

The file owner is:  root

I would expect to be able to run this as a regular user.  What I get is:
`date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`

I'd like to force a fixed date as a regular user (to get Flash to work) rather than having to use su and enter a password each time.  Sure appreciate any help.

(I tried this in the system rc files too but the VM still forces an updated date.)

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `setuid`, not `sticky`.

Comment: You are correct.  Sorry.